# Filtering Lookup for String x++

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, x++

I had lookup fields (type:int64, Extended from RefRecId) and I had written lookup filtering code for them but I had to convert them into strings ( I had added relations to make them lookup fields) But since they are "String" instead of "reference group" my code doesn't work. How can I filter them when they are 'string'. Here is my code for filtering for reference groups:

```
[FormControlEventHandler(formControlStr(InventSite, InventSite_MyField), FormControlEventType::Lookup)]
    public static void InventSite_MAndEDay_OnLookup(FormControl sender, FormControlEventArgs e)

    {
        SysReferenceTableLookup tableLookup = SysReferenceTableLookup::newParameters(tableNum(ReferenceTables), sender);
        Query query = new Query();
        InventSite inventSite;


        QueryBuildDataSource qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(ReferenceTables));

        qbds.addRange(fieldNum(ReferenceTables,ReferenceTablesType )).value(queryValue(ReferenceTablesTypeBaseEnum::MyField));

        tableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(ReferenceTables, Name ));
        tableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(ReferenceTables, Description ));


        tableLookup.parmQuery(query);
        tableLookup.performFormLookup();
```

[image: Error]

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks and regards...

Comment: Did you copy the right event handler? The error is pretty straight forward and it looks like the issue is with your argument `FormControl sender` when it's expecting `FormReferenceControl`

Comment: Yes, I copied the "OnLookup EventHandler', it is expecting the reference control but My lookup field is a string. When I use RefRecId this code works fine but I had to add the field as a string and make relation to lookup and lookup works fine but code doesn't

Comment: We can't see the objects you've created, but the problem is straight forward. The lookup is passing string control and that's not what it's expecting. Look at other reference control lookups, such as things relating to addresses for examples.

Answer (score 0):

use sysTableLookup instead of SysReferenceTableLookup

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).